# Convert clause to a Fun

Tags: erlang

How to represent this clause in one line using Fun.

```
perms([]) -> [[]];
perms(L) -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- perms(L--[H])].
```

Comment: That is one function with two clauses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are seeking is for a fun to be "self-recursive".

The fun syntax is not able to refer to itself inside the fun body, so one need to use a trick where the fun to call is a parameter. This is commonly referred to as the ycombinator.

Some example code will likely describe it better:

```
permutator() ->
  fun 
    ([], _F) ->
      [[]];
    (L, F) ->
      [ [H|T] || H <- L, T <- F(L--[H], F)]
  end.

do_permutate(L) ->
  P = permutator(),
  P(L, P).
```

As you can see this is quite awkward. If you just wanted to refer to the perms functions of yours, you can use the code: `fun perms/1`.

Answer (score 3):

I also got another answer similar to Christian.

```
5> Perms = fun(X) -> Fun = fun([],F) -> [[]]; (L,F) -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- F(L--[H],F)] end, Fun(X, Fun) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
6> Perms("cat").
["cat","cta","act","atc","tca","tac"]
```